# djoser не сохраняет пароль пользователя

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, authenticationtoken

Использую djoser с django rest framework. При попытке зарегистрировать пользователя djoser не выдает никаких ошибок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при попытке получить токен выдает ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И справедливо, т.к. никакого пароля в базе нет:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему djoser не хочет сохранять пароль я понять не могу.

settings.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'djoser',
    'Users',
    'Farms'
]
#Конфигурация REST
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.authtoken import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
]
```

При чем получение токена работает нормально если этому же пользователю задать пароль через админку.
Помогите, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо было в менеджере пользователей добавить  **user.set_password(password)**

```py
class Manager(UserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Пользователь должен иметь email')
        user=self.model(email=email,)
        user.set_password(password) #вот тут
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        user=self.model(email=email,)
        # user.username=""
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```